# Isolate a a substring within quotes from an entire line

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, replace, trim

To start here is an example of a line I am trying to manipulate:

```
  trait slot QName(PrivateNamespace("*", "com.company.assembleegameclient.ui:StatusBar"), "_-0IA") type QName(PackageNamespace(""), "Boolean") value False() end
```

I wrote a code that will go through and read through each line and stop at the appropriate line.  What I am trying to achieve now is to read through the characters and save just the

```
_-0IA
```

to a new string.  I tried using Trim(), Replace(), and indexof so far but I am having a ton of difficulties because of the quotation marks.  Has anyone deal with this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your source string will always follow a strict format with only some data changes, something like this might work:

```
    'Split the string by "," and extract the 3rd element.  Trim the space and _
     quotation mark from the front and extract the first 5 characters.
    Dim targetstr As String = sourcestr.Split(","c)(2).TrimStart(" """.ToCharArray).Substring(0, 5)
```

If the length of the target string is variable it can be done like this:

```
    Dim temp As String = teststr.Split(","c)(2).TrimStart(" """.ToCharArray)
    'Use the index of the next quotation mark instead of a fixed length
    Dim targetstr As String = temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf(""""c))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will play around with your idea and see what I can do.  I didn't know that you could use split in that way. Could you explain what the c at the end of you last string means?

Comment: the `c` is VB's way of denoting a literal char.  Because a quotation mark is VB's way of denoting a string literal it needs to be escaped by doubling it up